# SQL Server nested reporting structure / hierarchical

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an table like this

```
Id       Name        ReportingId
==
1        Stala       Null
2        Coma        1
3        Rita        1
4        Rosy        2
5        sss         4
```

I want a recursive query to find all reporting ids in single column.

For example for id 5 the output should be up to null always

```
4
2
1
null
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's an example using a recursive common table expression (CTE):

```
; with  cte as
        (
        select  ReportingID
        from    YourTable
        where   id = 5
        union all
        select  yt.ReportingID
        from    YourTable yt
        join    cte
        on      cte.ReportingID = yt.id
        )
select  *
from    cte
```

[Example on SQL Fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4d501/4)

Answer (score 2):

Somthing like this:

**Test data**

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Id int,Name VARCHAR(5),ReportingId INT)

INSERT INTO @T
VALUES
    (1,'Stala',Null),
    (2,'Coma',1),
    (3,'Rita',1),
    (4,'Rosy',2),
    (5,'sss',4)
```

**Query**

```
;WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        NULL AS Id,
        t.ReportingId
    FROM
        @T AS t
    WHERE
        t.Id=5
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t.Id,
        t.ReportingId
    FROM
        @T AS t
        JOIN CTE
            ON t.Id=CTE.ReportingId
)
SELECT
    CTE.Id
FROM
    CTE
```

**Result**

```
NULL
4
2
1
```